# ArrayList not storing values

Tags: java, android, random, arraylist, logcat

I am new to the concept of ArrayLists. I am using them as I want a dynamic array that isn't limited in the size of how many values it can hold in sequence. But the method I am using is not storing values correctly. I only keeps one value being the value 1. My code is as follows:

```
public void Rand(){
Random rand = new Random();
int Val = rand.nextInt(5); 
ArrayList<Integer> ValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ValList.add(Val);
Log.d("LOOK", Integer.toString(ValList));   
Log.i("VALUE LIST ", ValList.size()+" <<<<LIST HERE"); }
```

This process is called in oncreate and then returned to on a loop Ideally every time this class runs a new random number will be added to the array in sequence.

This is the relevant info on the logcat:

```
03-05 19:15:15.020: D/LOOK(21325): 3
03-05 19:15:15.020: I/VALUE LIST(20883): 1 <<<<LIST HERE
03-05 19:15:15.040: D/LOOK(21325): 5
03-05 19:15:15.040: I/VALUE LIST(20883): 1 <<<<LIST HERE
```

As you can see it only stores the value 1 even though the random value is not 1. Am I using the wrong type of array or implementing it incorrectly?

The output i'd want to see is something like this:

```
03-05 19:15:15.020: D/LOOK(21325): 3
03-05 19:15:15.020: I/VALUE LIST(20883): 3 <<<<LIST HERE
03-05 19:15:15.040: D/LOOK(21325): 5
03-05 19:15:15.040: I/VALUE LIST(20883): 3, 5 <<<<LIST HERE
```

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into formatting your code - and following normal Java naming conventions. They would both make your code a lot easier to read, and therefore make it easier to help you.

Comment: What does `Integer.toString(ValList)` mean? ValList is not an Integer.

Comment: @m0skit0 It should throw a compile-time error.

Comment: You could just read the documentation and avoid all of these problems.  Oh, and learn how to use the debugger.  it will teach you more than all the posts on StackOverflow.  Just saying...

Comment: If what you want is print the list, just use `Log.d("LOOK", ValList)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because, Your `ArrayList<Integer> ValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` has local scope for `Rand()` method only, So its has new instance every time you called `Rand()` function.

Just declare `ArrayList<Integer> ValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` as class level scope.

And use,

Like,

```
// Class level member declaration
ArrayList<Integer> ValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void Rand(){
          Random rand = new Random();
          int Val = rand.nextInt(5); 

          ValList.add(Val);
          Log.d("LOOK", ValList.toString()); 
          // Also here you are printing size of Arraylist not a content of arraylest
          Log.i("VALUE LIST ", ValList.size()+" <<<<LIST HERE"); 
 }
```

To print specific object value you have to get object from ArrayList using `.get()` with position of object, or use `.toString()` to print all list contents

```
Log.i("VALUE LIST ", ValList.toString()+" <<<<LIST items"); // using .toString() to print all contents of List
```

**Update:**

As I have doubt over this line throws Exception (But from your logcat its working fine, as list contains only one item)

```
Log.d("LOOK", Integer.toString(ValList));
```

As you are trying to print values of list `valList`, simply use `.toString()` like, `ValList.toString()`

Comment: You repeated the error that OP is printing the size of the List, not the contents.

Comment: These answers both address a problem the OP has. Don't make it a pissing match.

Comment: You should also be able to use toString() from ArrayList to print out all of the elements in ValList, ie. `Log.i("VALUE LIST ", ValList + " <<<<LIST HERE");`

Comment: Also, while I'm here, as mentioned in comments in the OP, `Integer.toString(ValList)` should throw a compile-time error. Not sure what he's trying to do in this line.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print size of your list.

`Log.i("VALUE LIST ", ValList.size()+" <<<<LIST HERE"); }`  // wrong (as per ques)

If you want to know what your array contains, try to print the content of your array.

Comment: Why all the down votes? This is the correct answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: But it's actually the answer to the question.

Comment: `Am I using the wrong type of array or implementing it incorrectly?` A comment helps that.

Comment: These answers both address a problem the OP has. Don't make it a pissing match.

Comment: One line can make a big difference ;)

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya because the list always prints `1` as size. It should print 2, 3 or more per method call, and that's the specific issue. That's why this doesn't solve the problem **at all**.

Comment: @jalynn2 the correct answer for this question is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886141/1065197)

Comment: @DaveS no, it doesn't addres the problem. This answer should be a comment instead (a bad one, let me say).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think the confusion here is that this does address **a** problem.  Just perhaps not the [most important](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28886141/1065197) problem.  Therefore this _does answer part_ of the question... which I guess is still an answer...

Comment: @chancea sadly bad answers are also supported. There's nothing I can do against it.